# How to get displayName (Name, Surname) from external organization smtp address in Outlook API?

Tags: vba, api, outlook, office365, ms-office

all, and thanks for your support.

I have a list of e-mails (ex: johndoe@company1.com, maryjane@company2.com) and need their DisplayTo names.

By "DisplayTo" I mean the name that appears after the first e-mail is sent ("ABC" in red).
[image]

So it should be something like "John Doe" or "Jane, Mary", which is how future e-mails to them appear (only the first one appears as name@company.com).

The Address Catalog only has internal company e-mails. I could not find a way to get this information in Outlook API documentation, is there a way to do this?

Thanks a million!

Comment: Obs: just for your information, I need their DisplayTo names because AdvancedSearch works with parameter DisplayTo (urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto), but not with to (urn:schemas:httpmail:to).

Answer (score 3):

Pass the SMTP address to `Namespace.CreateRecipient` (returns `Recipient` object). Call `Recipient.Resolve`, then use `Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.FirstName/LastName/etc` (error / null checking omitted).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!
As I was not finding a solution, I found a workaround: write in tiny (on invisible color, same as background) letters "emailSentTo:xxx@yyy.com" at the body of the email. Then, use AdvancedSearch with argument "urn:schemas:httpmail:textDescription" like %emailSentTo:xxx@yyy.com". 

I will try your suggestion when I'm able to, but thanks in advance!